# Как получить значение, вычисленное в функции и использовать его в другом месте

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

У меня есть функция, которая вычисляет количество выбранных дней, которые выбрал пользователь из календаря jquery datepicker. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это значение потом использовать в другом месте.
Пробовал выносить объявление переменной days за функцию, но тогда days underfined, потому что пользователь не выбрал данные, если поставить таймер, то такой вариант сработает, но один раз.
Тогда я попробовал использовать callback(), на что получал ошибку "t is not a function", которую исправить так и не смог. Скорее всего делал это как-то неправильно.

```
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(),
        dateFormat:'mm.dd.yyyy',
        onSelect = function daysGetter(selectedDates){
            var mdy = selectedDates.split('              ');
            var arr = mdy +' ';
            var splitted1 = arr.split('.');
            var splitted1String = splitted1 + ' ';
            var splittedFinal = splitted1String.split(',');
            
            [splittedFinal[0], splittedFinal[2]] = [splittedFinal[2], splittedFinal[0]];
            [splittedFinal[1],splittedFinal[2]] =[splittedFinal[2], splittedFinal[1]];
            [splittedFinal[3], splittedFinal[5]] = [splittedFinal[5], splittedFinal[3]];
            [splittedFinal[4], splittedFinal[5]]=[splittedFinal[5], splittedFinal[4]];
 
            var date1 = [splittedFinal[0], splittedFinal[1], splittedFinal[2]].toString();
            var date2 = [splittedFinal[3], splittedFinal[4], splittedFinal[5]].toString();
            var firstDate = new Date(date1);
            var secondDate = new Date(date2);
            var  days = Math.floor((secondDate.getTime(firstDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
            var daysCount = document.getElementById("daysCount");
            var daysPrice = document.getElementById("daysPrice");
            if(isNaN(days)==false){
                daysCount.innerHTML = days;
                var calculate = days * 3.2 * 1000;
                price = calculate.toFixed(0);
                daysPrice.innerHTML = price;
            }
            }
    })
```